# ensuring for loop doesnt run multiple times over the same value

Tags: python

So here's my code(python):

```
mdi_chart = {'Blood Sugar': 120, 'Carb Intake' : 76, 'Carb Dose' : 0.95, 'High Blood Sugar Dose' : 0.0, 'Total Dose' : 1.0, 'Lantis or Levemir' : 0}
for value in mdi_chart.values():
     for key in mdi_chart.keys():
           if mdi_chart[key] == value:
                 print(key, mdi_chart[key])
```

my output looks like this:

```
Blood Sugar 120
Carb Intake 76
Carb Dose 0.95
High Blood Sugar Dose 0.0
Lantis or Levemir 0
Total Dose 1.0
High Blood Sugar Dose 0.0
Lantis or Levemir 0
```

As you can see, the High Blood Sugar Dose and Lantis or Levemir keys are outputted twice, once as expected, but again at the end of the program. I assume the problem is a result of them sharing the same value. Is there anyway around this to output these keys only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .items() method for iterating over a dictionary.

```
mdi_chart = {'Blood Sugar': 120, 'Carb Intake' : 76, 'Carb Dose' : 0.95, 'High Blood Sugar Dose' : 0.0, 'Total Dose' : 1.0, 'Lantis or Levemir' : 0}

for key,value in mdi_chart.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: @Matiis Thanks alot! I ran the code and it worked great. Problem debugged!

Answer (score 1):

There is a great method that dictionaries have: `.items()`:

```py
mdi_chart = {'Blood Sugar': 120, 'Carb Intake' : 76, 'Carb Dose' : 0.95, 'High Blood Sugar Dose' : 0.0, 'Total Dose' : 1.0, 'Lantis or Levemir' : 0}

for key, value in mdi_chart.items():
    print(key, value)
```

the method `.items()` basically returns a list that contains tuples with key, value pairs so You can easily unpack both of those values each iteration

Oh, and the reason that Your code printed those keys, values twice is because they had the same value and since You were iterating over the whole dictionary each time the values matched twice